# Is it possible to copy text from a webpage and retain the fonts in the CSS?

Tags: html, javascript, css, jquery

When a user copies the text he/she is not able to copy it with font and style.

font and style is not added to the text copied on clipboard.

```
<div class="box"> <p class="textstyle" id="FasterOne" > HELLO GUYZ</p> </div>
```

CSS I have imported font from Google:

```
#FasterOne{ font-family: 'Faster One',cursive; }
```

Now I want that if a user selects this paragraph he/she could use it with its font.

Comment: as far as I know, it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to retain the font unless you have it on your computer and you copy-paste it in a way that includes the formatting. In short, the font doesn't get carried.

You can [download](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Faster+One) the Faster One font from Google Fonts though.

Comment: I have imported this font via link so now i have to download and add it through font face? IS this that you mean??

Comment: @dkgameryt, yes, you would have to download it and install it on your computer.

Comment: No bro i have installed and added font through font face but still while we copy text from website it isn't working!! Please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11111111111111111111